# multithread function restart pattern/solution

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have the following scenario:

One thread is iterating over a list data structure in method A of class X.  That data structure is a cache. At any time, we can get a call to a method B in class X saying our cache is out of date.  In that case, we need to restart function A if we are currently in function A, since the iteration over that data structure could us to find data that is no longer present.  We can count on Method B not being called twice at the same time(Method A will have time to complete).

Is this possible?  I am working with C++.  Note that simply locking the cache is not enough.  If we lock the cache and we get a call saying the cache is out of date, we need to right away restart function A for proper behaviour.

This wouldn't work correctly, but I will attempt to show what I need:

```
Class X
{
    Method A
    {
        for each //data structure
        {
            // do processing

            // check if our cache is out of date
            if(mRestart)
            {
                while(!mReadyToStart)
                    ; //wait

                mRestart = false;
                mReadyToStart = false;

                //Break, and call something that will recall this function.
            }                
            else
                return result; //return means we never needed to restart.
        }
    }

    Method B
    {
        mRestart = true;

        //Do processing

        mReadyToRestart = true;            
    }

    bool mRestart; // Init to false in constructor
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use synchronization mechanisms to protect the `mRestart`, `mReadyToRestart` members and the data structures you're working on, from concurrent access.

Depending on your particular needs, OS and build environment you could either use c++11 standard mutexes or condition variables, or other low level OS methods, or frameworks (e.g. boost::thread) to realize this in c++.

Comment: If I use mutex to lock the data structure in method A, how do I find out within the critical section of method A when the cache is out of date?

Comment: Have a 'cache valid' indicator (e.g. as condition variable) you're going to check on each iteration in the `for` loop and bail out if it's set to false (if this doesn't fit, please explain more detailed what you're considering your _critical section_).

Comment: And I didn't explicitely say 'use mutexes'. E.g. semaphores are good (better?) synch mechanisms for such stuff because you can notify any blocking sink waiters about changes in the source (cache) using a 'broadcast' mechanism. Unfortunately the c++11 standard doesn't provide a semaphore class or similar, but you can easily simulate this, using a special condition variable implementation.

Comment: ... a suitable reader/writer lock model could also fit your use case. Depends on the details of the `// D(d)o processing` stuff.
I hope I gave some useful hints ...